# Layout appears when set to toRightOf but when set to toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I am trying to make a layout with labels for FABs, but I have a problem with my RelativeLayout. The second RelativeLayout only appears when it is set to be to the right of the first, but not when set to be to the left. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".StartAndLogActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_start_and_log" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ActionButtonAndLabelContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_new_bank_purchase" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_NewTrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_trade" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_ShowMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewTrade"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_show_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HI"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This yields:

[image]

My other code (which does not work) is this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_start_and_log" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ActionButtonAndLabelContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_new_bank_purchase" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_NewTrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_trade" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB_ShowMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewTrade"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_show_menu" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HI"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This code yields:

[image]

Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: I see android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer" on both of them ...

Comment: it is bad idea to put RelativeLayout in RelativeLayout. Use one instead and place layouts inside with right properties. That's all

Comment: Thank you, @Shine. It has been Fixed.

Comment: @V.Kalyuzhnyu How exactly would I do that? Please leave an answer with example code. I do not exactly understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is its Working But your are unable to see that as its goes left beyond the display

Try setting First Relative layout to right and your good to go, use this like

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">
//First Layout contents
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer">
//Second Layout contents
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
  <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_ActionButtonAndLabelContainer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_FloatingActionButtonContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_new_bank_purchase" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FAB_NewTrade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_trade" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FAB_ShowMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/FAB_NewTrade"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin" 
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_show_menu" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/FAB_ShowMenu">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO,  HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HELLO, HI"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That means that your solution is working, but you can't see the TextView on the Left because "there is no space", since the parent layout's width is set to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FAB_NewBankPurchase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A short example. Every element of RelativeLayout has relative! position. So use one relative parent